# How to add a cron job in linux

Tags: linux, cron

I am using sphinx for searching. I get new data everyday which is added in the database.

I have to add this data into the sphinx search index so that it can be searched. For that I need to reindex the sphinx search index at regular intervals.

How can I set a cron in linux to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a crontab is defined like this:

```
MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD
```

so if you want to run a task on a daily basis try:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/your/script
```

that will trigger the launch of your script everyday at 0:00

---

For more details, see the [cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info)

Comment: Just a one thing to mention: crontab can be edited using `crontab -e` command or editing `/etc/crontab` file.

Comment: @DragonJake ... and those two have slightly different syntax, the personal crontab missing the `user` column from `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: Also make sure that your crontab ends with an empty line.