# form auto submit without opening the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, webkit

I created a application which is running in webkit browser, which will submit form (input fields type is hidden) with click on submit button. and it working fine for me.

is there any way to submit the form without opening the application by every week monday.

My form sample code in below:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">

        function init()
        {

            SnmpGet(null,"public",".1.8.53.3.6.1.7.1", model, modelfail);

        }



            function model( request, response ) 
            {
                var modelresp = SnmpParseGet(response);
                document.getElementById("model").value = modelresp.returnValue;

            SnmpGet(null,"public",".1.8.53.3.6.1.3.1", serialno, serialnofail);
            }

            function modelfail( request, response ) 
            {

            }
            function serialno( request, response ) 
            {
                var serialnoresp = SnmpParseGet(response);
                document.getElementById("sno").value = serialnoresp.returnValue;

            }

            function serialnofail( request, response ) 
            {

            }
            </script>
<body>
<form action="http://mywebsite/submit.php" method="post" id="form1">

<input type="hidden" id="sno" value="sno" name="sno">

<input type="hidden" id="model" value="model" name="model">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton" border="2" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

any advice or suggestion highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please show us what you've already done so far to solve your problem. Where's your javascript approach?

Comment: Is there any javascript/jquery code related to this form?

Comment: yes I am using javascript to change value of hidden field (edited the sample code)

Answer (score 1):

You have to crate s cronjob that executes the php behind the form!

[How to add a cron job in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945806/how-to-add-a-cron-job-in-linux)

Comment: Google for create a cronjob

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a pragmatic way of getting a form to auto submit like that no. If it is simply a bit of code that needs to be run then you are better looking at a scheduled job.

Comment: is this will work without opening the app, I am a newbie can you explain more